# Loading page in frame using WPF. frame can redirect into page. but design not Loaded

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm WPF developer i need to load multiple page. Some Codes try working but design not loaded 
below page C# code.
**page C#**

```
 public partial class Dashboard : Page
    {
        public Dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show("Working");
        }
    }
```

below page xml code
**page XML**

```
<Page x:Class="Project.View.Dashboard"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.View"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Title="Dashboard">

    <Grid Background="Black" >

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

below window c# code
**Window C#**

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          frame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Dashboard());        
        }
   }
```

below window XML code
**Window XML**

```
<Window x:Class="Project.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Name="MainWindow1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid>
<Frame x:Name="frame" Background="Violet" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>

</Grid>
</window>
```

Comment: Why do you use Frame? What happened to a ContentControl?

Comment: yeah, that's correct. but i need page..